# Is it illegal to name a variable with a numeric first character?

Tags: c#, winforms

Trying to declare this:

```
private const string 5dfgfdgfdg = "watever";
```

But it gives me an error. Once I remove the "5" it works.

Why does it do that? Is that a deliberate design decision?

Comment: Variables names are not allowed to start with numbers - it's in the spec.

Comment: There are precious few languages that allow that. Things that start with digits are numbers. Take `5E3` and `5f` for example. What languages are you used to?

Comment: I don't mean to nit pick but that is a horrible variable name. Variable names should give you some idea of what they are for/contain. After reading a basic C# book I would highly recommend reading Code Complete. You should always write code that is easy to maintain and read, you will be thankful when you come back to make changes to the code.

Comment: Hi, the variable name used here is obviously an example. You think I would really name a variable "5dfgfdgfdg"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable names cannot begin with a number. [Here is some more detailed information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Identifiers (like variable names) cannot start with a digit. A less formal explanation can be found here: http://www.codeguru.com/columns/csharp_learning/article.php/c6753